# Express middleware Login

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

Quisiera saber como es que puedo hacer que el usuario después de hacer login no pueda regresar a la pagina de login ?
Estoy utilizando Passport.js puedo registrar y hacer login,

Lo que yo quiero conseguir es que si esta autenticado y regrese al login lo redirija a /profile.

//Middleware

```
if(req.Authenticated()) 
{
   return next();
}

res.redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

El propio passport.js en la documentación te explica cómo hacerlo.

¿Estás usando la estrategia local con sesiones? Si es así passport te introduce el objeto user loguedo en la req. (Req.user).

De todas formas esta comprobación lo tienes que hacer en la ruta.

De memoria la comprobación que debes hacer es algo así:

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    If (req.user)
         res.redirect('/profile' });
    Else
         //lo que sea 
});

Si revisas la documentación de passport creo recordar que te explica bien como hacerlo, porque puede que tenga una opción mejor.

¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Si amigo, ya lo resolvi , unicamente me faltaba utilizar return res.redirect();